# Issue in retrieving same size image from phone storage to application activity

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-bitmap

I have saved an image from activity1 to internal storage in png format with 960*960 dimensions, the size is 5.8kb. From gallery again retrieving the same 960*960 5.8kb image into activity2 of the same app. Now when I save the same image from this activity2 to my gallery now image details is 960*960 and 4.8kb. This is stopping me from retrieving the pixel information from activity2 image which is the core requirement of my application. I want suggestions what can I do to save and retrieve image of same size.

Thank you in advance..

this is the code to save image from activity 1.

```
    public void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap){
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/My folder to save");
    String receiverN = receiverName.getText().toString();

    myDir.mkdirs();
    //name convention--------------------------------------------->>
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String month, day, year, hour, minute, second;
    month = ""+ (c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
    day = "" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    year = "" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    hour = ""+c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    if(hour.equals("0")) hour = "0"+hour;
    minute = "" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    if (seconds<10) second = "0"+ seconds;
    else second = ""+seconds;

    String fname = receiverN + "-" + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + "_"  + month + "-" + day + "-" + year +".png";
    //name convention ends----------------------------------------->>

    File file = new File (myDir, fname);


    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        String[] paths = {file.toString()};
        String[] mimeTypes = {"/image/png"};
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, paths, mimeTypes, null);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now I close app and go to gallery where it will be stored in "My folder to save" folder with 960*960 pixel dimensions and 5.8kb size. I will share this image to my app and this image will land to activity2 of same application. Here I want to get those pixels I processed before call of saveImage method in activity1. 
Some pixels gives me same data and some not.

this is the code in activity2 to get the image from gellery to activity2.

```
onCreate{
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type.startsWith("image/")){
        try {
            handleSendImage(intent);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void handleSendImage(Intent intent) throws IOException {
    Uri imageUri =  intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (imageUri != null) {
        myImageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imageUri);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(myImageBitmap);
    }
}
```

I have saved image from this activity2 also using saveImage method to observe the change and after saving it shows 960*960 dimensions and 4.8kb instead of 5.8kb which was originally saved from activity1.

Thus I have figured that I am not able to get those pixels I want so help me with saving and retrieving image lossless.

Hope this information is usefull, thank you in advance.

Comment: Show your code. Quality should not degrade.

Comment: `saved an image from activity1 to gallery `. One can not save images to the Gallery app as the Gallery app is an app and no storage location. Please rephrase.

Comment: Not really as its still in the subject.

Comment: changed it and added code also to make you understand the flow..

Comment: `public void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap)`. You did notYou also did not tell where activity 2 retrieves the image from. So much is unclear. Please start with an image file if possible.

Comment: If you save bitmaps to file then why dont you just give the file path to the second activity?

Comment: How is Intent.ACTION_SEND activated? Why dont you just let activity 1 start activity 2?

Comment: `Now when I save the same image from this activity2 to my gallery ` To your gallery? What's that? `changed it ` ???